# Deploy Java Web Application + MongoDB on AWS

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services, deployment

I have Java Web Application that runs on tomcat server, without any frameworks. My application works with MongoDB and I need to deploy it to AWS.

What are my steps need to be done?

1. Deploy war on Elastic Beanstalk?
2. Install Mongo on EC2?

What would be the process?

Actually, I don't understand how to use Mongo in AWS. Deploying war is simple but how to connect this project with my database?

Comment: What have you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB runs well in the cloud, both managed by yourself or through **Atlas**, the MongoDB-as-a-Service offering from MongoDB.  The latter is probably the easiest way to get yourself started and may provide all the capability you require without having to take on management yourself.
https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas

Disclosure:  I used to work at MongoDB